# Bundle config not reflecting added references

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, reference

I am trying to implement Autocomplete Textbox functionality in my MVC application, in which i need to add the following references in my page to get the functionalities working.

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here, when I add these references to the bundle config file, the js files and css files aren't reflected in the project.

**Code for References**

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));
```

Could you please let me know what I am missing in the above.

Comment: how are you referencing your bundles in your `cshtml` page?

Comment: Hi, The bundles are being refered through Layout.cshtml.

Comment: The bundle is being referred by using Layout.cshtml file using below  lines of code.   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") and @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Comment: when you view the source by "right clicking" do you see the `<scripe>` and `<link>` tags created by `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

if not work check you route

Comment: The above bundle reference are already present in Layout.cshtml, still it's not working.

Comment: Are any exceptions in browser console to help us what is proplem

Comment: No exception found